# angular - ag-grid add a date picker to a date cell for editing

Tags: angular, datepicker, ag-grid-angular

I have an ag-grid in angular with a cell with a date in it.  I would like to add a date picker but this just seems so complex.  I would ideally like to use [mydatepicker](http://kekeh.github.io/mydatepicker/) as this is being used elsewhere in the app.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, there is a little bit of work required to teach ag-gird how to use a third-party date picker.

But they have really good docs, which provide goot code examples on how to do it. I have done it several times now, it works really well (after a bit of practise)

Check it out: https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/component-date/

Comment: Thanks for the response Sebastian but I really do think I am missing something as you are not the first person to say 'They have really good docs' but they make no sense to me.  I will continue to play about and I am sure something will stick but for now I continue hating ag-grid

Comment: Ag-Grid third party date pickers are not something you implemenrt in 10 min. Ask again if you have more specific questions or get stuck in the process.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian I appreciate your time.